# ftpUpload error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:

Tags: android, image-uploading

I want to upload a image to server . Here is my code :

MainAcitvity.java :

```
String filePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+
                                  "/cloze_screenshots/20141014_055246.jpg";     
boolean ftpclient.ftpUpload(filePath,"20141014_055246.jpg","./bigmimi/public_html/testing/"+"947917688555565/",cntx);
```

ftpclient.java :

```
public boolean ftpUpload(String srcFilePath, String desFileName,
                         String desDirectory, Context context)
{
    boolean status = false;
    try {
       // FileInputStream srcFileStream = new FileInputStream(srcFilePath);

        FileInputStream srcFileStream = context.openFileInput(srcFilePath);

        // change working directory to the destination directory
        //if (ftpChangeDirectory(desDirectory)) {
            status = mFTPClient.storeFile(desFileName, srcFileStream);
        //}

        srcFileStream.close();
        return status;
    } 
    catch (Exception e) {
        //Log.d(TAG, "upload failed: " + e);
        Log.e("go","error: "+ e);
    }

    return status;
}
```

I get an error :

```
 error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: File /storage/emulated/0/cloze_screenshots/20141014_055246.jpg contains a path separator
```

Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stats in docs `openFileInput()`

> Open a private file associated with this Context's application package
>   for reading.
>
> **Parameters**
>
> **name**  The name of the file to open; can not contain path
>   separators.

i.e.  `openFileInput()` doesn't accept paths, only a file name if you want to access a path, **use new File(path)** to get file name from path and then pass it in `openFileInput()`.

in your code change

```
 FileInputStream srcFileStream = context.openFileInput(srcFilePath);
```

to

```
 FileInputStream srcFileStream = context.openFileInput("20141014_055246.jpg");
```

**Edit**

Your files in SD card and you are using `openFileInput()` which open internal file. so to get files from sdcard,use

```
File mFile = new File(srcFilePath);
```

and use `srcFileStream` as

```
    FileInputStream srcFileStream = new FileInputStream(mFile);
```

instead of

```
    FileInputStream srcFileStream = context.openFileInput(srcFilePath);
```

Comment: I get new error : error: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/data/com.example.friendpicker/files/20141014_072939.jpg: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)

Comment: @hiein2003 Did you change as suggested.Please post your code also which you update

Comment: @hiein2003 it seems that your image files in sdcard and you are trying to get those from internal memory.

Comment: I changed my code as your advice :
File f =  new File(srcFilePath);
String filename = f.getName();
FileInputStream srcFileStream = context.openFileInput(filename);

Is it correct ?

Comment: Yes , I want to upload the image which is in SDcard .

Comment: @hiein2003 but **/data/data/com.example.friendpicker/files/20141014_072939.jpg:** is internal location.Is this file "20141014_072939" in sdcard.

Comment: yes, it is in SD card. I might not speak clearly, I want to upload the image which is locate in the SDcard not the internal location. But your methods seems to get the image from internal location. Please help me.